# How to remove HTML tags from ckeditor in Laravel

Tags: laravel

[image: Image showing html tags <p></p>]

Html tags displayed in the body having  paragraph tags. The body is entered through ckeditor

Comment: to render html tags use {!! !!} instead of {{ }}

Answer (score 2):

In order to output html in blade you can use `{!! !!}` instead of `{{ }}`

Comment: @BLPraveen please consider accepting the answer than. Thanks.

Comment: But watch out for security issues like XSS please